# Unable to add Pixiemedia_ImageCarousel extension to cms page

Tags: magento2, extensions, magento2.2.6

I have successfully installed Pixiemedia Image Carousel extension from the magento marketplace and made a group and added images in that. The next step should be to add that in any block or page (as per the description in the official Pixiemedia page). But I could not find any instruction on how exactly to do that.

(I am guessing it should be something like `{{block ...` etc)

Below is my default.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2017 Pixie Media. All rights reserved.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="PixieMedia_ImageCarousel::css/pixiemedia-imagecarousel.css" />
    </head> 
    <body>
    </body>
</page>
```

The folders I can see in the installed directory, i.e. **C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\pixiemedia\image-carousel** is as follows:

[image]

Any help is appreciated and Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the Pixiemedia Image Carousel from back end or using  your custom theme.

Below I describe both process.

***Pixiemedia Image Carousel From Admin Panel:***

- Log in into you Magento 2 Admin Panel
- Go To CONTENT -> PAGES
- Find out the CMS page for the Home Page (urk key = "home" )
- click "Edit" under Action Tab to open the CMS page in edit mode
- on the content area, Please paste the below code and replace  **CAROUSEL_GROUP_Id** with your Pixiemedia Image Carousel Goup ID (Go to *CONTENT* -> *Carousel Groups*)

  ***{{block class="PixieMedia\ImageCarousel\Block\Carousel" groupid="CAROUSEL_GROUP_Id" name="my_carousel_cms" template="carousel.phtml"}}***
- refresh you Magento cache

***Pixiemedia Image Carousel From Custom Theme:***

If you are using any custom theme then you can implement Pixiemedia Image Carousel. Step are describe below

***Assume your custom theme name is "Vendor_customtheme"***

- create the CMS index page lay out file.
  ***/app/design/frontend/Vendor/customtheme/Magento_Cms/layout/cms_index_index.xml***

File : **cms_index_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>  
        <referenceContainer name="content">           
           <block class="PixieMedia\ImageCarousel\Block\Carousel" name="my_carousel" template="PixieMedia_ImageCarousel::carousel.phtml">
                <arguments>
                <argument name="groupid" xsi:type="string">CAROUSEL_GROUP_Id</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

- Please replace CAROUSEL_GROUP_Id with your with your Pixiemedia Image Carousel Group ID (Go to CONTENT -> Carousel Groups to know find out Carousel group id )
- Refresh your Magento cache

[image]